# Shorten this CSS code

Tags: css

i have this css code, and i want to shorten it.

```
#one{
background: #6cab26;
background-image: url(#1_img_url),-moz-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* FF3.6+ */
}

#two{
background: #6cab26;
background-image: url(#2_img_url),-moz-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* FF3.6+ */

}

#three{
background: #6cab26;
background-image: url(#3_img_url),-moz-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* FF3.6+ */
}
```

This css code is to use gradient with background!

it's working so fine, but how to short it?

i want something like this

```
#one,#two,#three{
background: #6cab26;
background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999);
}

#one{
background-image: url(#1_img_url)
}
#two{
background-image: url(#2_img_url)
}
#three{
background-image: url(#3_img_url)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, CSS currently does *not* provide a way to override a separate background-image layer when using multiple background-image layers.

You can take advantage of CSS preprocessors like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/), and then you could save your gradient in variable to prevent its duplication. For example, in LESS:

```
@grad: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999);

#one {
    background-image: url(#1_img_url), @grad;
}

#two {
    background-image: url(#2_img_url), @grad;
}

#three{
    background-image: url(#3_img_url), @grad;
}
```

Comment: i am css coder since 3 years.. but this is first time i know i can set varibales in css!! This is good soultion Thanks alot (f)

Comment: i want shorten this code because i'll use this (futare/service) with all other browsers like (-webkit,-o,filter,etc) and i think this code will be a biggest code ever ... So what you think?

Comment: be aware these are not variables in css (coming soon) but variables in a css pre-processor

Comment: @luca i was reading more about the css variables and i fount it is a harmful!.. i'll use more html elements to shorten my code as much as possible as well as i was need it to use an image inside a colorized button by gradient

Answer (score 2):

EDIT

your code is as short as possible without using preprocessors as Marat suggested (credit to him!)

Comment: @luca i'll try this code now, but i think i've already tested it and not working..!!

Comment: @luca this is just an example for my code,my code is too big!, this thing cost me about 20 line!! (for all browsers)